# "print array in main thread swift3 Xcode 8"

Tags: arrays, multithreading, swift3, xcode8

I learn swift not long ago and i have some problem in this code print array:

```
class InitController: UIViewController {
public var initdata = [(id: String, name: String)]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    print("initdata", initdata)
    init_auth()

}
func init_auth(){
    let json: [String: Any] = ["token": UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token"), "id":UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "id")]
    //let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    let url = "http://some_ip/api"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    //print(jsonData)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
        }
        let responceJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responceJSON = responceJSON as? [String: Any]{
            let s = responceJSON["specialities"] as? NSDictionary
            let d = s?["items"] as! NSArray
            for i in d {
                let f = i as? NSDictionary
                self.initdata.append((id: f?["id"] as! String, name: f?["name"] as! String))
            }
        }
    }
    print("list", self.initdata)
    task.resume()
}
```

}
initdata is empty array, but I get some json file and append this array. I try print initdata, but this array is nil. I think maybe problem in thread, but I don't know how realize this.

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [MCVE]

Comment: URLSession is asynchronous. You print initData long, long, long before it has been downloaded. And please add some error handling. EVERY ! is a point where your app can crash. At least learn "if let".

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
func init_auth(){
    let json: [String: Any] = ["token": UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "token"), "id":UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "id")]
    //let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
    let url = "http://some_ip/api"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    request.httpBody = jsonData
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    //print(jsonData)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, responce, error in guard let data = data, error == nil else {
        print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No data")
        return
        }
        let responceJSON = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [])
        if let responceJSON = responceJSON as? [String: Any]{
            let s = responceJSON["specialities"] as? NSDictionary
            let d = s?["items"] as! NSArray
            for i in d {
                let f = i as? NSDictionary
                self.initdata.append((id: f?["id"] as! String, name: f?["name"] as! String))
            }
            print("list", self.initdata)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```